# how to customize wp_nav_menu() fort icons

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

how can i add icon wo wp_nav_menus?..
this is the picture that i design

http://postimg.org/image/w7x2hfn75/

I want to make the first menu as an icon, are there possible way?..

my code

```
<?php 

    $defaults = array(
        'theme_location' => 'header-menu'
        );

    wp_nav_menu( $defaults ); 

?>
```

and i add the

```
'before'          => '',
```

it show the icon for every menus, i want single home icon

icon source http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/

Answer (score 2):

**Add Font Awesome 4 icons to your WordPress menus and site without touching a single line of code!**

> Install this wordpress plugin after active follow screenshort: [Font Awesome
>   4 Menus](https://wordpress.org/plugins/font-awesome-4-menus/)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using font awesome, you can simply add something like below on the navigation Item label when you create a menu,

```
<i class="fa fa-home"></i>
```

You can also add something in wordpress HTML menu structure using CSS or Jquery,

No need to use PHP for a very simple thing like that

Answer (score 0):

You can create the site from that design and after that post the link to that so that I can give you the code for replacing first menu item to add icon.. Thanks.